# why does this curl fetch from tmp inside container in k8s pod?

Tags: kubernetes, curl, containers

This deployment creates 1 pod that has init container in it. The container mounts volume into tmp/web-content and writes 1 single line 'check this out' to index.html

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-init-container
  namespace: mars
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      id: test-init-container
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        id: test-init-container
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: web-content
        emptyDir: {}
      initContainers:
      - name: init-con
        image: busybox:1.31.0
        command: ['sh', '-c' ,"echo 'check this out' > /tmp/web-content/index.html"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: web-content
          mountPath: /tmp/web-content/
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.17.3-alpine
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: web-content
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I fire up temporary pod to check if i can see this line 'check this out' using curl.

```
k run tmp --restart=Never --rm -i --image=nginx:alpine -- curl 10.0.0.67
```

It does show the line. However, how does curl know which directory to go in?
I dont specify it should go to /tmp/web-content explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just an elaboration of @P.... answer .**

- Following is creating a common storage space "tagged" with name "web-content"

```
     ​volumes:
     ​- name: web-content
       ​emptyDir: {}
```

- web-content is mount in location `/tmp/web-content/` on init container named `init-con` which is writing `check this out` in `index.html`

```
      initContainers:
      - name: init-con
        image: busybox:1.31.0
        command: ['sh', '-c' ,"echo 'check this out' > /tmp/web-content/index.html"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: web-content
          mountPath: /tmp/web-content/
```

- same `web-content` volume which has the `index.html` is being mounted as directory `/usr/share/nginx/html` so the `index.html` location will be seen as `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` . (**default landing page for nginx** ) for container `nginx`  hence it shows `check this out` when you curl to it.

```
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.17.3-alpine
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: web-content
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: this is easier to get, correct if wrong -  i mount SAME volume in diff directories? so curl reads from same volume?

Comment: yes .. you can mount same volume in **different directories for different contatiners** .curl from pod **tmp** is not reading the directory , it is just contacting the **nginx** container which is part of pod which is in turn child of the deploymet named **test-init-container**  , That container is reading  the content from the volume named **web-content**

Answer (score 2):

Its because of the `mountPath`:

> The root directive indicates the actual path on your hard drive where
> this virtual host's assets (HTML, images, CSS, and so on) are located,
> ie /usr/share/nginx/html. The index setting tells Nginx what file or
> files to serve when it's asked to display a directory

When you curl to default port 80, curl serve you back content of the html directory.
.